# Rails inserting invalid datetimes in created_at and updated_at

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mysql2, ruby-1.8

I am using Rails 3.2.2 on Ruby 1.8.7 with mysql2 0.3.11 (against a mysql 14.14 server), and sometimes a `created_at` or `updated_at` value will be an invalid DateTime, and cause my app to throw an exception with the message `"Invalid date: 2022-03-00 00:00:00"`.

I am not explicitly creating, setting, reading, or doing anything with the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns.

Inspecting the table through a `mysql` client, for the most part, the value in each of these columns is "`0000-00-00 00:00:00`", which ends up as `nil` in Rails. However, several rows show values such as "`2022-03-00 00:00:00`" (they are all different, though as far as I can tell, all in 2022).

Interestingly, I can't even run `.destroy()` from Rails, because it can't create the object.

What could be setting invalid dates for those columns?

Edit: This is happening for all tables. Here is my schema.rb, and all of the migrations for one of the tables: https://gist.github.com/2930655

**Edit2**: I solved it myself (see my answer below), but would appreciate if you'd weigh in on if it's a bug, and if so, which package the bug is with (ActiveRecord?).

Comment: what's your migration for that table and what's in schema.rb for it?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this was happening because I'd overloaded `Time#to_s`, causing invalid values to be sent in SQL (it was sending HH:MM:SS for DateTimes).

MySQL and SQLite both fail to parse DateTimes in this format, and result in garbage values, however, SQLite's values are never "invalid" according to Ruby, so I never noticed this during development.

Now, when I am saving an object that has a Time or DateTime in another column, and I set it to a Time/DateTime object, it is set correctly, so I am inclined to say that this is a bug.